# When the plural ends in "-ies", how do I know whether the singular ends in "-y" or "-ie"?

Tags: grammatical-number, orthography, rules

my question is how am I supposed to recognize a singular form of a noun which plural form ends with "ies"? As you can see "cookies" are a "cookie" when singular, but at the same time "flies" stand for a "fly". It seems there's no rule for this, so I am rather asking for a list of exceptions if you will. Thank you.

Comment: whoever downvoted this, please explain yourself

Comment: I understand your quandary, but asking for a list is probably going to get your question closed...

Comment: You're supposed to know the same way you're supposed to know the spelling of any other word: by learning it, and failing that, by looking it up in the dictionary. That makes this question general reference. (And even if it weren't, it's asking for a very long list—not one that can reasonably be compiled in a single answer—which makes it a bad fit for this site.)

Comment: Martha, is there a dictionary of plural forms in English? If so, I'd be glad if you could name it. By which I mean not a regular dictionary that has all the trivial forms, but rather a special one that focuses on a exceptional cases like ones that are in question.

Comment: @bonomo, no, there is no dictionary of plural forms in English. Like some other posters told you, "cookies" and "flies" are not "exceptional cases." Exceptional cases for human beings are both Marys, the Kennedys, etc.

Comment: Your question is based on a wrong assumption. There are no (synchronic) rules why you should spell a word with "y" or "ie". For example, the word "movie" was spelled both ways, "movie" and "movy" in the early 1900s. The word "copy" was originally "copye", with later forms "copie" and "coppie". We just learn them.

Comment: One consolation being that word forms may not change overnight. Once we learn/ document them, that should last some time.

Answer (score 6):

It turns out that you don't need to worry too much: it's something in the order of 100 times more likely that the base word ends in -y.

Common exceptions are:

- a few common monosyllabic words ("die", "lie", "tie", "pie") and compounds ("untie", "underlie"...);
- a few loanwords from French ("sortie", "crêperie", "cameraderie"...) plus one or two older loans that are now fairly well integrated (notably "calorie")
- a few informal words, which can actually often be spelt either way ("hippy/hippie", "sweety/sweetie", "movie", "druggy/druggie"...)
- the odd other word ("eerie", "zombie")

Overall, no need to lose too much sleep.

Comment: well, first of all thank you for understanding of my concerns, some people around don't seem to see this problem worth of discussion whatsoever, second, you insight's are really helpful, at the very least you gave few examples to google around, and at last, the problem I am dealing with is in domain of natural language processing, where I have to explain to a computer how to make a "cookie" out of "cookies" and a "fly" out of "flies", and that guys is not very cooperative, but nevertheless, thanks again!

Comment: A list, finally! Great work.  +1 won't do justice.

Comment: @bonomo If only you had stated that in your Q., people would've been maha impressed and you'd have got better response. :-)

Comment: Neil, we've only solved one part of OP's problem, that of finding the correct singular for a given plural.

Comment: Spelling: "movie" (one o), lose (one o).

Comment: Kris - wasn't that the problem? what was the other half?

Answer (score 0):

Cookie and fly are both regular English plurals.

The simplest and most common rule for plurals is add an 's'.
If the word ends in a 'y' remove it and add an 'ies' so fly->flies, spy->spies. The exception to this is if removing the 'y' leaves a vowel then you add an 's' to the 'y' so day->days

Comment: The OP is asking the other direction....what if you see a word like 'bogies' that seems to be used as a plural...is there a way to tell if the singular is 'bogy' or 'bogie'?

Comment: well well, what I was asking is a quite opposite situation, given a plural form "cookies", now how am I supposed to get a singular out of it, should I replace "ies" in "flies" with "y" or with "ie", now what should I do with "cookies"?

Comment: @bonomo - generally you can't. That's even how some words came about. The 'pea' really has a singular the same as the plural 'peas' but people assumed that remove the 's' was the singular and created a new word

Comment: nice, now does anybody have a list of exceptions at hands? :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct and practicable solution to your problem can only be a database lookup. No single algorithm will work, however complex it may be.

Have all the words, each with its corresponding plural forms (there will be more than one in some cases) in a db table. Index it on the plurals. Easier than it appears to be.

There will just be one hitch, still. What if two different words have the same plural form? I leave that as a separate exercise (that is to say "I don't know").

Comment: why do I need to keep ALL words in my db? while for most of them the plural/singular form can be calculated. i'd think i need to keep only exceptions there, which is what my question was about actually, i just thought maybe somebody has a list of them

Comment: Because you'd not know the "only exceptions" -- that is about getting real.

Comment: i am not getting you. cat/cats - a regular case, don't need to keep it, dog/dogs - same thing, mouse/mice - irregular - get into the database, what's the problem here?

Comment: On a different point, if anyone has such a list, they are more likely to be on SO or programmersSE than EL&U.

Comment: How'd you "know" *flies* was not regular? What is the algorithm that filters a word as a regular plural? Or even a plural at all, for that matter? No way. Programs do not have intuition -- we build that into them. On the other hand, by trying to define regular and irregular forms, we are building complexity into it.